# i want a picture as a background instead of a color

Tags: flutter, background

I want in my flutter app a picture as a background instead of a color

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJWo0.png)

Comment: Welcome NikoZDS. Do not post your code as image please.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/sample.jpg"),
          ),
        ),
        child: YourScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use `NetworkImage("Your_image_url")` for rendering network image in background